# How can I customize the message shown to a user who reaches a Guru Meditation error when making a request thru my Varnish server?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to customize what appears on the screen for a user when he reaches a Guru Meditation error screen, upon making an erring request to my backend, which has a Varnish reverse proxy in front. I have tried placing `log.info(client.ip)` in the different subroutines of default.vcl, only to run into compilation errors when trying to start the varnish service. I am using a Linux virtual machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. Have a look at the following tutorial I created: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/vcl-synthetic-output-template-file/.

### Modifying the synthetic output templates

Here's the VCL code you need to extend the regular `vcl_synth` subroutine in case you call `return(synth())` from your VCL code, as well as the code you need to extend `vcl_backend_response` in case of a backend fetch error:

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    set resp.body = regsuball(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/synth.html"),"<<REASON>>",resp.reason);
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set beresp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    set beresp.body = regsuball(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/synth.html"),"<<REASON>>",beresp.reason);
    return (deliver);
}
```

As explained in the tutorial, you can store the HTML code you want to display in an HTML and load this into your VCL output.

The trick is to put a `<<REASON>>` placeholder in your HTML where the actual error message gets parsed into.

### Adding custom logging to your VCL

If you want to add custom logging that gets sent to VSL, you can use the `std.log()` function that is part of `vmod_std`.

Here's some example VCL code that uses this function:

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

sub vcl_recv {
    std.log("Client IP: " + client.ip);
}
```

The log will be displayed through a `VCL_Log` tag in your VSL output.

If you want to filter out `VCL_Log` tags, you can use the following command:

```
varnishlog -g request -i VCL_Log
```

This is the output you may receive:

```
*   << Request  >> 32770
-   VCL_Log        Client IP: 127.0.0.1
**  << BeReq    >> 32771
```

If you're not filtering the `VCL_Log` tag, you'll see it appear in your VSL output if your run `varnishlog -g request`.

> **Tip:** if you want to see the full log transaction but only for a specific URL, just run `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"`. This will only display the logs for the homepage.

### Update: displaying the client IP in the synthetic output

The VCL code below injects the `X-Forwarded-For` header into the output by concatenating to the reason phrase:

```
vcl 4.1;

import std;

sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    set resp.body = regsuball(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/synth.html"),"<<REASON>>",resp.reason + " (" + req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ")");
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set beresp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    set beresp.body = regsuball(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/synth.html"),"<<REASON>>",beresp.reason + " (" + bereq.http.X-Forwarded-For + ")");
    return (deliver);
}
```

> It's also possible to provide a second placeholder in the template and perform an extra `regsuball()` call. But for the sake of simplicity, the `X-Forwarded-For` header is just attached to the reason string.

Comment: how can I get the client's IP address if there's a proxy betwen the client and varnish (like Caddy)?

Comment: It all depends on the TLS proxy you are using. If the proxy emits an `X-Forwarded-For` header, Varnish will  use that value and send it to the server. If not, Varnish will create an `X-Forwarded-For` header and use the proxy's IP address as the value. It is in your best interest to ensure the TLS proxy passes the original client IP under the form of an `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Comment: it does. In that case, how can I do this?

Comment: @TekDood Since you confirmed that your TLS proxy emits an `X-Forwarded-For` header, you don't have to do anything. The value you're looking for is in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. Use that value. If you're looking to store the client IP in the logs, alter your logging format and include `X-Forwarded-For`.

Comment: I'm looking to display the client's IP to the error Guru screen. Most places I've tried to grab the client's X-Forwarded-For and write it to something that can be read in backend_error, it causes a compilation error

Comment: @TekDood I updated the answer containing some VCL code that injects the `X-Forwarded-For` header into the synthetic output.